# Force malloc to pre-fault/MAP_POPULATE/MADV_WILLNEED all allocations for an entire program/process

Tags: memory-management, malloc, profiling, dynamic-memory-allocation, mmap

For the sake of some user-space performance profiling, I'd like to cleanly separate the costs of allocating memory from operations that access it. The application does no over-allocation, so every page that gets mapped will be faulted in, probably in code that runs shortly after its allocation.

What I'd like to do is set some flag, environment variable, something, to tell `malloc` that it should uniformly do the equivalent of calling `mmap(..., MAP_POPULATE)` or `madvise(..., MADV_WILLNEED)` or just touching every page of whatever it allocated itself. I haven't found any documentation, on any platform(!), that describes a way to do this. Is there some existing technique that's utterly undocumented, up to my ability to search? Is this a fundamentally misguided or bad idea?

If I wanted to implement this myself, I'm thinking of an `LD_PRELOAD` including just a reimplementation of `malloc` that calls the underlying `malloc` and then does the `madvise` thing (to be at least somewhat agnostic to huge pages behavior). Any reason that shouldn't work?

Comment: In case it's not obvious, I'm aware of the many questions and answers about calling `mmap` or `madvise` explicitly - the point is to avoid modifying an entire application and all of its libraries (and the Python and Fortran runtimes) to do so.

Comment: I am interested to know if/how much of a performance impact this has. If you don't mind, I would like to see the results of this benchmark. You might also try `calloc` as a low-speed baseline for context.

Comment: The point would be to ideally have *no* net performance impact. It should just move all the cost of compulsory page faults from the point of first use to the point of allocation. Of course, if the first use is far from the allocation, it could actually hurt performance, by screwing with the cache or even the TLB

Comment: Yes, there *shouldn't* be an impact (aside from the additional overhead of another function call). But, is there? Discovering the difference between what logically should happen versus what does happen is the point of the profiling, after all, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` is one of the most used, yet relatively slow functions in common use. As a result, it has received a lot of optimization attention over the years. I seriously doubt that any serious implementation of `malloc` does anything so slow as the string parsing that would be required to check an environment variable at every call.

`LD_PRELOAD` is not a bad idea, considering what you're doing, you wouldn't even need to recompile to switch between profile and release builds. If you're open to recompiling, I would suggest doing a `#define malloc(size) { malloc(size); mmap(...);}`. You could even do this at the compile command line via `-Dmalloc=...` (so long as the system malloc is not itself a define, which would overwrite the cli one).

Another option would be to find/implement a program that uses the debug interface to intercept and redirect calls to `malloc`. You could theoretically do this by messing with the post-compiled (or post-load) program's import section to point to your dll/so file.

**Edit:** On second thought, the define might not work on every allocation, since it is often implied by the compiler (e.g. `new`).